# How to create a design matrix for identification of differentially methylated regions between two sample sets?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

```
> head(ICGC_2)
             naive.1   memoryCS.1    naive.2   memoryCS.2   naive.3  memoryCS.3
cg00000029  0.6199970   0.5703951  0.6383819   0.5831206  0.7012571  0.6000816
cg00000108  0.9083578   0.9105157  0.9030611   0.9103147  0.9115842  0.8947593
cg00000109  0.8694214   0.7525098  0.8478160   0.7725212  0.8645145  0.7636347
cg00000165  0.1911901   0.3050081  0.1810569   0.3750369  0.2250429  0.3094155
cg00000236  0.8666489   0.8382011  0.8586420   0.8369283  0.8860430  0.8439371
cg00000289  0.6653662   0.5512665  0.5815338   0.4773868  0.6254710  0.5408634
```

Hello! In R I have a data frame that contains 450K methylation beta values for 6 samples, 3 naive B cell samples and 3 memoryCS samples. A section of this is pictured above. My eventual aim is to identify genomic regions that are differentially methylated in the naive samples compared to the memoryCS samples. I will do this with the Bioconductor package DMRcate. However, I first need to create a suitable design matrix. With regards to this I'm completely lost...

Can anyone help me understand how I can create factors using the naive and memoryCS data and then use these factors to create a design matrix?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you read vignette? https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DMRcate/inst/doc/DMRcate.pdf

Comment: The vignette doesn't really explain how the design matrix is set up

Comment: question marked as duplicate does